# How to normalize each column to its mean value

Tags: matlab, mean, normalize

I have one table with in y the regions, while in several years (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 etc). Each year has one value for each region. I would like to nomalize the data of each column. Is it possible to normalize using the mean of the year? I tried this, but I am not sure.

```
t=readtable('Cartel3.xlsx')
t_norm a= normalize((t{2:end, 2:end}),'norm')
```

I have two tables with different data. I would like to compare them.I was asked to use the annual average to normalize. But it is not clear for me, the formula.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include a simple example of expected output for a given input column? This will help better define which method of normalization you actually want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `normalize` directly on your `table` providing you specify the `'DataVariables'` parameter, like this:

```
>> t = table(["A";"B";"C"], [1;2;3], [0;10;20], 'VariableNames', {'Name', '2011', '2012'})
t =
  3x3 table
    Name    2011    2012
    ____    ____    ____
    "A"      1        0 
    "B"      2       10 
    "C"      3       20 
>> normalize(t, 'DataVariables', t.Properties.VariableNames(2:end))
ans =
  3x3 table
    Name    2011    2012
    ____    ____    ____
    "A"      -1      -1 
    "B"       0       0 
    "C"       1       1
```

There's a specific example like this [on the doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.normalize.html#mw_59fd0dba-eedf-4252-aedc-af300a50875b).

Comment: Note that `normalize` uses the zscore by default, the OP has tried to specify the method as the `norm` which I'm not sure is quite right either for their requested "normalize using the mean"... Might need more details from OP on their expected output to decide the normalisation method (and whether that method is available within `normalize`)